# What is CnosDB's strategy of spliting the exported CSVs?

Tags: cnosdb

I am exporting CSV files from cnosdb, following [docs/backup#export-as-csv](https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/latest/manage/backup.html#export-as-csv) and it gives me 3 CSV files, each file contains data of two sensors, seems cnosdb split the data by it's serie key, and then spliced some of them in one file.

I want to export the data of each sensor into a CSV file (example: for 6 sensors, 6 CSVs are expected), I can't find a way to do it.

Here are some steps to replay (insert data of 6 cpu cores, and export into 3 CSVs but not 6):

##### 1. Export cpu data into CSVs

Insesrt 6 rows, export into 3 CSVs.

```sql
❯ create table cpu( usage_user double,  tags(cpu, host) );
-- There arer 6 cores, 6 data for each core.
❯ insert into cpu(time, cpu, host, usage_user) values('2023-06-30T00:00:00', 'cpu0', 'e1', 0.1 );
❯ insert into cpu(time, cpu, host, usage_user) values('2023-06-30T00:00:00', 'cpu1', 'e1', 0.1 );
❯ insert into cpu(time, cpu, host, usage_user) values('2023-06-30T00:00:00', 'cpu2', 'e1', 0.1 );
❯ insert into cpu(time, cpu, host, usage_user) values('2023-06-30T00:00:00', 'cpu3', 'e1', 0.1 );
❯ insert into cpu(time, cpu, host, usage_user) values('2023-06-30T00:00:00', 'cpu4', 'e1', 0.1 );
❯ insert into cpu(time, cpu, host, usage_user) values('2023-06-30T00:00:00', 'cpu-total', 'e1', 0.1 );
❯ select count(*) from cpu;
+-----------------+
| COUNT(UInt8(1)) |
+-----------------+
| 6               |
+-----------------+
❯ copy into 'file:///tmp/cpu' from cpu file_format=(type='csv', delimiter=',');
+------+
| rows |
+------+
| 6    |
+------+
```

##### 2. There're 3 CSVs we've exported.

And each file has 2 rows.

```bash
$ ls /tmp/cpu
part-13208079990210775408-2-0.csv
part-14773625014335458202-4-0.csv
part-16759184562829806718-3-0.csv

$ cat /tmp/cpu/part-13208079990210775408-2-0.csv
time,cpu,host,usage_user
2023-06-30T00:00:00.000000000,cpu0,e1,0.1
2023-06-30T00:00:00.000000000,cpu1,e1,0.

$ cat /tmp/cpu/part-14773625014335458202-4-0.csv
time,cpu,host,usage_user
2023-06-30T00:00:00.000000000,cpu2,e1,0.1
2023-06-30T00:00:00.000000000,cpu3,e1,0.1

$ cat /tmp/cpu/part-16759184562829806718-3-0.csv
time,cpu,host,usage_user
2023-06-30T00:00:00.000000000,cpu4,e1,0.1
2023-06-30T00:00:00.000000000,cpu-total,e1,0.1
```

| file | core | core |
| --- | --- | --- |
| part-13208079990210775408-2-0.csv | cpu0,e1 | cpu1,e1 |
| part-14773625014335458202-4-0.csv | cpu2,e1 | cpu3,e1 |
| part-16759184562829806718-3-0.csv | cpu4,e1 | cpu-total,e1 |